# How to wait a few seconds to make sure nothing happens before executing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with 2 components (columns) that's needed to be dismissed when user done selecting. I want it to wait for user in 2 seconds before disappears. In those 2 seconds if user performs any selection it will continue to wait for another 2s. Here is my code to make it wait 2s before dismisses. Thank you.

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    double delayInSeconds = 2; // number of seconds to wait
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

         [self.view endEditing:YES];
    });
}
```

Comment: Use a timer. Reset it if the user does something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using a simple trick in `pickerView: titleForRow: forComponent:` with helpful suggestions from @XEDeveloper and @rmaddy. Here is my code:

```
NSTimer *timer;

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(dismiss) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
[timer invalidate];
if (component==0) {
    return [pickerFromArray objectAtIndex:row];
} else {
    return [pickerToArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(todo) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

---

```
-(void) todo {
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

to stop this

```
[timer invalidate];
```

Comment: I think this code doesn't reset when user perform selection action